# Roll a die according to the number of sides that the user enters

Tags: python, random, dice

I have created a program which rolls a die according to the number of sides that the user enters:

```
def var():

    import random

    dicesides = int(input("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice that is being thrown to have. The dice sides available are: 4, 6 and 12: "))
    script(dicesides, random)

def script(dicesides, random):

    if dicesides == 4:
        dice4 = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides))
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", dice4)

    elif dicesides == 6:
        dice6 = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides))
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", dice6)

    elif dicesides == 12:
        dice12 = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides))
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", dice12)

    elif dicesides != 4 or dicesides != 6 or dicesides != 12:
        print("That number is invalid. Please try again.")
        var()

    repeat = str(input("Repeat? Simply put yes or no : "))

    if repeat == "yes":
        var()
    else:
        quit()

var()
```

Is there a way to shorten this?

Comment: Given that you are using a computer random number generator, why not accept any number of sides?  Anything wrong with a d23?  At least 8 and 20 seem like they should be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables `dice4`. `dice6` and `dice12` are essentially the same variables, so let's give them the same name. It now happens that three of the cases are identical, and can be shortened to:

```
if dicesides != 4 or dicesides != 6 or dicesides != 12:
    print("That number is invalid. Please try again.")
    var()
else:
    score = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides))
    print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", score)
```

The test for allowed numbers of sides can be shortened to `dicesides not in [4, 6, 12]`, which more clearly shows what you are trying to express. This would allow you to include the number of sides as an optional parameter to the function – some people use 20-sided dices a lot. And actually, there is no reason why you would constrain the user to a certain number of sides anyway.

It is not clear to me what advantage recursion via the `var` method has over an ordinary loop. One *disadvantage* is that an avid player could theoretically overflow the stack….

It is also not clear why `random` is a parameter to the `script`.

You are using `random.randrange` wrong. The `help()` output on my system gives me:

> Choose a random item from `range(start, stop[, step])`.
>
> This fixes the problem with `randint()` which includes the endpoint; in Python this is usually not what you want.

This means that rolling a 6-sided die, you will invoke `random.randrange(1, 6)`, which returns a random int in the range `[1, 6)` – this excludes the number `6`, and you actually pick from `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Fix this either by `1 + random.randrange(0, dicesides)` or preferably `random.randint(1, dicesides)`.

Comment: `dicesides != 4 or dicesides != 6 or dicesides != 12` is always true, since `4 != 6`.  On the other hand, `dicesides not in [4, 6, 12]` can be false.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely! If you replace `dice4`, `dice6` and `dice12` with `rolled`, you'll see they all have the same code. At that point, just gate the shared code with something like `if dicesides in [4, 6, 12]:`, and change your final `elif` to an `else`.

Other comments:

- I would suggest not passing `random` to `script()` (which itself should have a better name, such as `roll`).
- The way you loop uses a technique that looks a lot like recursion. However your approach is not using this in any meaningful fashion. I would probably move the part of your code from `repeat = str(input(...` into `var()` (which itself should either have a more meaningful name, or at least a common name like `main`), and put this in a while loop.

Putting these together:

```
import random

def main():
    repeat = "yes"
    while repeat == "yes":
        dicesides = ...
        roll(dicesides)
        repeat = ...

def roll(dicesides):
    if dicesides in [4, 6, 12]:
        rolled = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides)) # but see amon's notes
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", rolled)
    else:
        print("That number is invalid. Please try again.")

main()
```

Note that this does result in a slight change on invalid input - it now asks you if you want to repeat.